# Wordpress usar ajax em página template

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Utilizando como base o tópico abaixo:
http://tableless.com.br/requisicoes-ajax-no-wordpress/

Fiz um código para ser executado usando ajax no meu projeto WP, o detalhe é que este código está em uma área do site externa. Para que esta área seja acessível usei um template dentro do tema. Achei que seria correto colocar o código que registra as chamadas ajax neste template. Ficou algo assim:

```
// Adicionando um script para o Wordpress
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'secure_enqueue_script');
function secure_enqueue_script(){
    wp_register_script('secure-ajax-access', 
            esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'js_global' => 1), site_url())));
    wp_enqueue_script('secure-ajax-access');
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'javascript_variaveis');
function javascript_variaveis(){
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['js_global'])) return;

    $nonce = wp_create_nonce('senha_do_dia_nonce');

    $variaveis_javascript = array(
        'senha_do_dia_nonce' => $nonce,
        'xhr_url'            => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    );

    $new_array = array();
    foreach ($variaveis_javascript as $key => $value) {
        $new_array[] = esc_js($key).":'".esc_js($value)."'";
    }

    header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
    printf('var %s;','js_global',implode(',',$new_array));
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_senha_dia', 'senha_dia');
function senha_dia(){
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['senha_do_dia_nonce'], 'senha_do_dia_nonce')) {
        echo '401';
        die();
    }

    $data_senha = $_POST['data_senha'];         
    $senha = array('senha' => calculaSenha($data_senha));

    echo json_encode($senha);
}

include_once(get_template_directory().'/painel-administrativo/index.php');
```

Para fazer a chamada no *front end*, usei o código como abaixo em um arquivo `script.js`, que é carregado pelo arquivo: `painel-administrativo/index.php`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#consultar').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var dados_envio = {
            'senha_do_dia_nonce' : js_global.senha_do_dia_nonce,
            'data_senha' : $('#diasenha').val(),
            'action':'senha_dia'
        }

        $.ajax({
           url: js_global.xhr_url,
           type: 'POST',
           data: dados_envio,
           dataType: 'JSON',
           success: function(response){
               if (response == '401'){
                   console.error('Requisição inválida')
               } else {
                   console.log(response);
                   $('#senha').val(response);
               }

           }
        });

    });
}
```

Ele retorna um erro no console do navegador:

```
ReferenceError: js_global is not defined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### O problema específico

A variável global `js_global` não está definida na página. Me parece que você está carregando o template sem usar a query `?js_global=1` aí a checagem em `template_redirect` passa batida e a variável não fica disponível.

Isso dito: essa implementação não tá legal. Parece uma mistura de dois métodos diferentes sem um ganho específico.

### Como fazer Ajax em WordPress do jeito certo:

Antes de começar: existem alguns jeitos certos.

1. O mais comum é fazer as requisições diretamente ao arquivo `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` e recebê-las no server-side usando os hooks `wp_ajax_{nome_da_funcao}` e `wp_ajax_nopriv_{nome_da_funcao}`. Esse é o método recomendado no [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) e em inúmeros outros recursos online. Eu aprendi usando [esse link](http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) muitos anos atrás, e ainda está atual. Esse método tem a desvantagem de não ser cacheável, a cada requisição ele carrega o back-end inteiro. Ele foi desenvolvido primordialmente pra ser usado no back-end, mas também funciona no front se o volume de requisições for pequeno.
2. Menos comum mas também muito útil é usar a [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) para criar endpoints específicos e tratar os dados ali. Esse método é 100% cacheável porque funciona interrompendo o carregamento ainda cedo, e funciona bem com sites de maior tráfego, para requisições no front-end.
3. Quando o WordPress 4.7 sair vai haver também a [API REST nativa](http://v2.wp-api.org/) e aí é outra conversa e isso vai ficar muito mais interessante.

Por enquanto vamos ver como implementar esse mesmo código usando os métodos 1 e 2. Nos dois casos vamos usar o mesmo formulário:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="dados" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'recebe_dados', 'nonce' ); ?>

    <input type="submit" name="Enviar" id="botao" />
</form>
```

### Método 1, usando `admin-ajax.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'registrar_e_chamar_scripts' );
// wp_ajax_{nome} roda somente quando o usuário está logado
add_action( 'wp_ajax_funcao_que_recebe_os_dados', 'funcao_que_recebe_os_dados' );
// wp_ajax_nopriv_{nome} roda somente quando o usuário não está logado
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_funcao_que_recebe_os_dados', 'funcao_que_recebe_os_dados' );

/**
 * Essa é função que define os arquivos js a serem usados e as variáveis globais 
 * que estarão disponíveis
 * @hook wp_enqueue_scripts
 */
function registrar_e_chamar_scripts() {
    // O primeiro passo é determinar em qual arquivo está o nosso javascript, 
    // se ele tem alguma dependência, usa um numero de versão e se deve ser 
    // declarado em <head> ou ao final do HTML. wp_register_script
    wp_register_script( 'nosso_js', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nosso.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

    // Uma vez registrado, colocamos na fila para ser inserido no tema. 
    // wp_enqueue_script() se encarrega de chamar o jQuery antes do nosso 
    // arquivo pra que as funções estejam disponíveis. wp_enqueue_script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nosso_js' );

    // Agora vamos criar um objeto global 'nosso_js' para uso com o script, 
    // ele terá uma referência à url que precisamos chamar
    // wp_localize_script
    wp_localize_script( 'nosso_js', 'nosso_js', 
        array( 'ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

/**
 * Essa é a função que será chamada pelo Ajax. O arquivo admin_ajax age como 
 * roteador junto com as actions definidas e traz as requisições para serem 
 * recebidas aqui
 *
 * @hook wp_ajax_funcao_que_recebe_os_dados
 * @hook wp_ajax_nopriv_funcao_que_recebe_os_dados
 */
function funcao_que_recebe_os_dados() {

    // A primeira coisa a fazer é tratar o input do usuário
    $request = stripslashes_deep( $_POST );

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $request['nonce'], 'recebe_dados' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error('Nonce inválido');
    }

    // Se necessário também faça um check de permissões para o usuário
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error('Usuário não tem permissões suficientes');
    }

    // Por fim, trate o request como desejar e envie a resposta
    $resposta = funcao_que_produz_a_resposta( $request['dados'] );

    // wp_send_json, wp_send_json_success e wp_send_json_error são funções 
    // padrão para retornar valores via Ajax. Elas se encarregam de enviar 
    // os cabeçalhos corretos e transformar os valores em JSON
    wp_send_json( $resposta );
}
```

no arquivo `nosso.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('#botao').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
       url: nosso_js.ajax,
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
        'action': 'funcao_que_recebe_os_dados',
        'nonce': jQuery('#nonce').val(),
        'dados': jQuery('#dados').val()
       },
       success: function(response){
           // fazer alguma coisa com a resposta
           console.log(response);
       }
    });   
  });
});
```

---

### Método 2, usando a `Rewrite API`:

no `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'init', 'criar_endpoints' );
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'funcao_que_recebe_os_dados' );
/**
 * Registra os novos endpoints. Qualquer alteração nessa função deve ser
 * seguida de uma limpeza nos permalinks. Basta salvar os permalinks novamente 
 * pelo painel.
 */
function criar_endpoints() {
    // adiciona um parâmetro "dados" às variáveis interpretadas nativamente
    add_rewrite_tag( '%dados%', '([0-9]+)' );
    // opcional, permite chamadas para URLs específicas tipo /api/dados/dado1 
    // (ao invés de ?dados=dado1), para deixar as URLs mais amigáveis. 
    // Não está sendo usado no exemplo.
    add_rewrite_rule( 'api/dados/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?dados=$matches[1]', 'top' );

}

/**
 * Recebe e responde às requisições
 */
function funcao_que_recebe_os_dados() {
    global $wp_query;

    $dados = $wp_query->get( 'dados' );
    $nonce = $_GET['nonce'];

    if ( empty( $dados ) || empty( $nonce ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Conferindo o nonce
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'recebe_dados' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error('Nonce inválido');
    }

    // Conferindo permissões
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error('Usuário não tem permissões suficientes');
    }

    $dados = stripslashes_deep( $dados );
    $resposta = funcao_que_produz_a_resposta( $dados ); 

    // Enviando a resposta
    wp_send_json( $resposta );
}
```

no arquivo `nosso.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('#botao').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
       data: {
        'nonce': jQuery('#nonce').val(),
        'dados': jQuery('#dados').val()
       },
       success: function(response){
           // fazer alguma coisa com a resposta
           console.log(response);
       }
    });   
  });
});
```

Comment: Muito boa explicação @RicardoMaraleida, seria interessante assim que o Wordpress 4.7 sair você fazer uma complementação nesta resposta para ajudar a galera que desenvolve em Wordpress.