# Como faço para trocar a categoria do loop wordpress via ajax

Tags: wordpress, loop

Eu vou ter um select com 3 categorias, toda vez que eu trocar o valor do select ele muda o resultado do lop 
Exemplo:

```
<select>
  <option value="Noticias">Noticias</option>
  <option value="Shopping">Saab</option>
  <option value="Musica">Musica</option>
</select>


<section class="container">
        <div class="list_article" role="carousel">
            <?php $args = array(
                    'post_type'=>'novidades',
                    'numberposts'=> 3
                );
                $counter = 0;
                $my_posts = get_posts($args);
                if( $my_posts ): foreach( $my_posts as $post ) :   setup_postdata($post); ; $counter++ ?>
                    <article class="_card">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                         <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                        </a>
                    </article>
                <?php
                wp_reset_query();
                endforeach; else: ?>
                    <p>Nada encontrado.</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </section><!-- end container -->
```

Comment: O que você já tentou? jQuery.load pode te ajudar http://api.jquery.com/load/ se o seu caso for bem simples. Se precisar de ajuda com Ajax em WordPress eu fiz uma explicação detalhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160069/5213