# Exibição do resultado da pesquisa Wordpress na index

Tags: php, wordpress

Fala galera,

Eu inseri a pesquisa na minha index vide o código

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Como eu consigo fazer a busca me retornar o resultado na própria index? no caso o visitante vai digitar lá na pesquisa e o resultado exibir abaixo do campo da pesquisa? Hoje o Wordpress ao clicar em pesquisar leva para uma url de pesquisa.

Comment: Imagino que você queira dizer "na index sem recarregar a página", certo? Você precisa usar Ajax pra isso. Nessa resposta tem links e exemplos de como fazer: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160069/5213

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida também seria legal não recarregar não tinha pensado nisso.. mais a questão que eu falo é quando digita-se algo na pesquisa e da enter (isso em widget) ele vai para outro link exemplo: http://linkdosite.com/?s=teste